# Rails app with multiple domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma, mina

Im getting stuck at this. I have a Rails App, that running on DO droplet and  over 10 domain, Nginx as web server and Puma. The difference between websites is  style for each domain and their db. So i cant figure out how to make it works. 
As i can see, I should create a separate socket for every site and configure redirection.

Locally it is working like: in `.env` file i define some site i.e. `domain1.com`and app choosing certain style and. 
Sorry for mistakes, I maybe wrong, im not a developer, i just need to deploy it. At this time it is hosting on Heroku, separate app for separate site.

Comment: As soon as it depends on env variables, you`ll need to create separate apps on your server for each domain. I suggest hiring a professional for this task as it is not that simple.

Comment: Switching styles based on domain seems fine, but switching the database makes me think this needs to be multiple apps deployed separately. Do you need to have a different database per site?

Comment: Yes, thank you for answer. And yes, there is different database per site. So im gonna deploy every app separate

Answer (score 0):

You can create different tasks for different domains. Each task would just set the appropriate variables.

Take a look at https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/blob/master/docs/cookbook.md#multi-environment-deploy

Comment: My task  is a little different than that, but anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rails makes it easy to handle multiple domains with just the routes.rb file. You can add constraints to your routes such that those endpoints and controllers only respond to requests made to a certain domain.

Constraints could look like this:

```
constraints(ShopDomain) do
  resources :shop
  get '/subscription', to: 'shop#subscription'
  root to: 'shop#index'
end
```

You could define constraints such as if a domain or subdomain matches a string. That could look like this:

```
class ShopDomain
  def self.matches? request
    request.subdomain == 'shop'
  end
end
```

Now in your case, each site has its own controllers that have their own views and styles.

I wrote a more in-depth description of this strategy on my blog,
[here](https://pushschool.com/routing-multiple-domains-in-ruby-on-rails-app).